# xaml and C# should be equivalent, but they're not

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a one-row grid in xaml, and then add rows dynamically in C#. Yet, although they ALMOST line up, they don't QUITE do so. Why would this be, when the code is the same?

The most pertinent part of the XAML is:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The  most pertinent part of the C# is:

```
Grid grd = new Grid();
ColumnDefinition c0 = new ColumnDefinition(); 
c0.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star); 
ColumnDefinition c1 = new ColumnDefinition(); 
c1.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star); 
ColumnDefinition c2 = new ColumnDefinition(); 
c2.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
ColumnDefinition c3 = new ColumnDefinition();
c3.Width = new GridLength(4, GridUnitType.Star);
ColumnDefinition c4 = new ColumnDefinition();
c4.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
ColumnDefinition c5 = new ColumnDefinition();
c5.Width = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star);
ColumnDefinition c6 = new ColumnDefinition();
c6.Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star);
ColumnDefinition c7 = new ColumnDefinition();
c7.Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star);
grd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c0);
grd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
grd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c2);
grd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c3);
grd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c4);
grd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c5);
grd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c6);
grd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c7);
// Add it to the StackPanel
spNufan.Children.Add(grd);
```

[Screenshot http://getfile6.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2012-02-16/EHnCudinikxcfprHxjywowEcwBssAcpbdchkeinAqJdhvuwDIhJxoonrjGEq/MisalignedColumns.bmp.scaled1000.jpg](http://getfile6.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2012-02-16/EHnCudinikxcfprHxjywowEcwBssAcpbdchkeinAqJdhvuwDIhJxoonrjGEq/MisalignedColumns.bmp.scaled1000.jpg)

## Updated

It seems I have to choose between having all my columns line up and having a really wide form OR allowing "cells" to wrap with wiggly/wavy column alignment.

At first I had wrapping working fine, but the columns weren't exactly aligned, but now that I've added the following (SharedSizeGroup element) to my xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spNufan" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
        Orientation="Vertical">
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ZeroethColumn" Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FirstColumn" Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SecondColumn" Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ThirdColumn" Width="4*" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FourthColumn" Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FifthColumn" Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SixthColumn" Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SeventhColumn" Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Margin="2"
               TextAlignment="Left"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               . . .
```

...it no longer does (allow the cells to wrap as they should), although I have TextWrapping set to "Wrap"

Here is my pertinent C#:

```
Grid grd = new Grid();
grd.ShowGridLines = true;
ColumnDefinition c0 = new ColumnDefinition(); 
c0.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
c0.SharedSizeGroup = "ZeroethColumn";
. . .
spNufan.Children.Add(grd);
. . .
TextBlock tbDateTime = new TextBlock();
tbDateTime.Margin = _margin;
tbDateTime.Background = scb;
tbDateTime.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
tbDateTime.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
tbDateTime.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
tbDateTime.Text = ADateTime.ToString();
Grid.SetColumn(tbDateTime, LogParsePumpViewerConsts.GRID_COL_DATETIME);
grd.Children.Add(tbDateTime);
```

Comment: Can you provide screenshots to show visually how they differ?

Comment: Do you have auto generate columns set to true..? if so set that to false also this spNufan.Children.Add(grd);  looks like something from a post on here yesterday.. for the .Children.Add() method

Comment: And did you carefully check all Margin and Padding settings?

Comment: Is there a way to add scream shots here?

Comment: I temporarily added a screen shot here: http://warbler.posterous.com/misaligned-columns

Comment: Margin is the same: set to 2 in the xaml, and in C# it's: System.Windows.Thickness _margin = new Thickness(2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different content in the orange group as compared to the red group. The text overflow will make the column sizes slightly different. Most notably in the first column, 2/12/2012 is larger than 2/8/2012.

Comment: Ah, yes, each row's columns are relative to its own row, so that makes sense. So...is there a way to force each row to use the same widths as the first one without specifying absolute widths?

Comment: Yes, columns can share a size. Peruse http://wpf.2000things.com/2011/11/07/424-getting-data-bound-items-in-a-listbox-to-be-a-consistent-size/ for details.

Comment: I tried setting SharedSizeGroup via <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ZeroethColumn" Width="*" />
in xaml and c0.SharedSizeGroup = "ZeroethColumn"; in C#, but it's still skewed - some of the columns bear a striking resemblance to the Leaning Tower of Pisa.

Comment: Adding Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" to the StackPanel's properties in xaml _does_ make all the column widths uniform across rows, but it disregards the "TextWrapping = Wrap" of the individual columns, thus ending up with a form that is so wide not even Evel Knievel would have dared attempt to jump it.